# What's preventing the file from being uploaded

Tags: php, html, mysql, file

In my code, I have a file input which I use along with textareas, my HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="includes/listing1.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image_file">
<textarea name="title" cols="30" rows="2" placeholder="Title"></textarea>
<textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
<textarea name="price" cols="5" rows="1" placeholder="Price"></textarea>
<select multiple="multiple" name="categories">
  <option value="bla1">bla1</option>
  <option value="bla2">bla2</option>
  <option value="bla3">bla3</option>
  <option value="bla4">bla4</option>
  <option value="bla5">bla5</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="vendor" value="<?php $_SESSION['UserUid']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="listpost-submit" value="Post listing">
```

Notice I have the file input and the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, I have this PHP code:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['listpost-submit'])) {

            require 'dbh.inc.php';

$filename = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
$target = 'site_images/';
$filetarget = $target.$filename;
$tempfilename = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$cat = $_POST['categories'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$result = move_uploaded_file($tempfilename, $filetarget);

if ($result == true) {
    echo '<div>Your file has been uploaded!</div>';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO listings 
 (`image`,`title`,`description`,`price`,`category`,`vendor`,`imgpath`) 
VALUES ('$filename', '$title', '$description', '$price', '$cat', '$vendor', 
'$filetarget')";
header("Location: ../index.php?listing=posted");
exit();
}
elseif (empty($title) || empty($description) || empty($price) || empty($cat) 
|| $vendor) {
    echo '<div>Something is missing!</div>';
    exit();
}
else {
    echo '<div>There was a problem uploading your file!</div>';
    exit();
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Database structure:

```
idListings(int) imgListings(varchar(200))   titleListings   descriptionListings priceListings   categoryListings    vendorListings  imgpathListings(varchar(250))
```

At the moment if I run the code it will tell me that the file can't be uploaded, I tried changing to a file with no spaces in between but that didn't work either, my question is how I can fix this so that all files can be stored in the database. Please tell me if the information is inadequate!

Comment: PHP as a index called 'error' that you can check to see  what kind o problem do you have uploading the file. Check https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Can you check the site_images folder if the file was uploaded there. If not check your configuration file.

Comment: @Marco I did that, it returned zero.

Comment: Try uploading a different file, sometimes the browser does some weird shit if you try to upload the same file twice in row.

Comment: @Marco that returned the same error, if we look at the code, could there be something preventing it from being uploaded?

Comment: No, everything seems fine. Probably has something to do with directory / file permissions or server related. If you are using apache, you can try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/463479/apache-how-to-log-the-file-name-and-size-of-file-uploads

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: You also define a query string and never actually execute it. A way to avoid this mistake is to always supply the query string directly to the `prepare()` function, not by defining a variable first.

Comment: Can be more things wrong like 1) missing write permission ideally this should be `chmod 755` on the `site_images` path, 2) the uploaded file is to big? 3) Besides you know that every file can be uploaded right even PHP files which might a able to get executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You need to user index tmp_name that is the original filename on the /tmp folder.

Change from:

```
$tempfilename = $_FILES['image_file']['name'];
```

To:

```
$tempfilename = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'];
```

It should work.

Comment: PHP move uploaded file to a temporary folder location. That is the temp name that it  will move it to your desired filename. This information exists at index 'tmp_name', you you var_dump it you will get something  like '/tmp/some-random-filename'. This info is the first argument of move_uploaded_file. You are getting 'name' index where you should get 'tmp_name' get it?

Comment: Tried `$dump = var_dump($tempfilename);` and then `move_uploaded_file($dump, $filetarget);` I then get the temporary name and I don't know what to do next, still a bit unclear!